# how to disabling notification using selenium for firefox browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

I want to complete disable the notification when i launch a firefox browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Chrome notifications (Selenium)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343423/disable-chrome-notifications-selenium)

Answer (score 7):

For different browsers/drivers there are different profiles/options that need to be set:

**Firefox**

```
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffprofile.setPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

**Chrome** (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34368704/904375)

```
Map prefs = new HashMap();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: FirefoxProfile is deprecated

Comment: Since FirefoxProfile got deprecated, we can use FirefoxOptions in the below way
------
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled",false);
webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);

Answer (score 2):

For the latest versions of Firefox (I believe its from version 44), just change the value of dom.webnotifications.enabled to false. By default, it's true which allows pop-up.
Code here:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(new FirefoxProfile());
options.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python:

```
options = Options()
options.set_preference('dom.webnotifications.enabled', False)
```

Comment: Running this as options = Options is confusing thins. make sure to use options=Options(). Don't forget the paranthesis