# How to disable push-notifications using Selenium for Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I want to disable the notification when I launch Firefox browser through Selenium  Webdriver.
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43908995/how-to-disabling-notification-using-selenium-for-firefox-browser), but it's deprecated and does not work for me on Firefox (it works perfectly on Chrome though).

I'm use this dependency for my *pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your *usecase* is to disable the *notification* following are the options :

- To disable [**Push Notification**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox) in **Firefox** browser client take help of a *FirefoxProfile* and pass the *Keys* **dom.webnotifications.enabled** and **dom.push.enabled** along with the desired *Value* as **false** :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
  ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
  FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("debanjan");
  testprofile.setPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
  testprofile.setPreference("dom.push.enabled", false);
  DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, testprofile);
  FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
  opt.merge(dc);
  WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
  driver.get("https://www.ndtv.com/");
  ```

**Note** : This method uses an existing `FirefoxProfile` by the name **debanjan** stored in my local system which was created following the documentation at [**Creating a new Firefox profile on Windows**](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows)

- To disable *notification* in **Chrome** browser client take help of a *setExperimentalOption()* to pass a *HashMap* containing **profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications** with *Value* as **2** :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
  Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
  prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
  prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
  options.addArguments("start-maximized");
  options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
  options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
  options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.ndtv.com/");
  ```

Comment: This works for Firefox, but I changed one line:   

  `FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("default");`

This is universal solution? It will be works on another hosts/os for my teammates?

Comment: @vixsimplex I have added a reference with respect to you question within the comments. However as per best practices avoid using the **default** _FirefoxProfile_ as it may contain _add-ons_, _bookmarks_, etc. As a result you may face **Timeout Errors** while loading the _default_ profile.

Comment: @DebanjanB I've used this solution for chrome, but the notification still comes 'xxxx wants to show notification'. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015268/selenium-newer-chrome-cannot-disable-browser-notification-tried-other-solns Can you please take a look?

Comment: Thanks++, Python version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75762833/10284437