# Selenium allow site to save files

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have this popup

[image]

and I'm trying to make it either allow, deny with ChromeDriver.

Translates to: secure.runescape.com wants the following

Save files on this device (Allow and deny as options)

Tried:

```
 ChromeOptions chrome_options = new ChromeOptions();
                chrome_options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
```

This still showed up the popup

```
IAlert simpleAlert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                simpleAlert.Accept();
```

This gave the error that there is no alert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to click Allow on Show Notifications popup using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684175/how-to-click-allow-on-show-notifications-popup-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Have to tried to use Action class , something like this : IAlert simpleAlert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert(); simpleAlert.Accept();

Comment: @KyllianLissens What is the popup all about? Can you translate it to us in plain English?

Comment: @PixelEinstein already tried the solutions there, didn't work

Comment: @DebanjanB Check the edit

Comment: @KyllianLissens Check this discussion [How to disable push-notifications using Selenium for Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741876/how-to-disable-push-notifications-using-selenium-for-firefox/49745879#49745879)

Comment: @DebanjanB C# has no maps, and no setexperimentaloption.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable notfications, code belongs to java. You can change it into C sharp

```
ChromeOptions chrome_options = new ChromeOptions();
chrome_options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path of chromedriver.exe);
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver(chrome_options);
```

Comment: He wants to know how to select options from the notification, not disabling the notifications.