# Unable to locate element error in Java-Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have written code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("New CDA Request")));
element.click();
```

Getting below error while running the script:

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Feb 15, 2021 5:18:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.className: New CDA Request (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at Automation.CreateCDARequest.main(CreateCDARequest.java:30)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".New\ CDA\ Request"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)
```

Before the error, I am getting a pop-up in screen to allow notification. Is the pop-up creating issue?

[image]

[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: How are we supposed to know how to reach that element from just a screnshot without knowing the actual html with class names and ids? Maybe `By.className("New CDA Request"))` is correct, but as far as I know css class names cannot contain spaces, so that selector looks suspicious to me.

Comment: Please refer attached image for the path. Let me know what path to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New CDA Request** is the *`textContent`* of the `<button>`. To click on the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'slds-button') and text()='New CDA Request']")).click();
  ```

---

Ideally to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'slds-button') and text()='New CDA Request']"))).click();
  ```

---

### Notification popup

You can find a couple of relevant discussion on handling the Notification popup in:

- [How to disable push-notifications using Selenium for Firefox and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741876/how-to-disable-push-notifications-using-selenium-for-firefox/49745879#49745879)
- [How to allow or deny notification geo-location microphone camera pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007699/how-to-allow-or-deny-notification-geo-location-microphone-camera-pop-up/48017495#48017495)