# How to handle notification alert using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do i handle notification alert/popup using selenium code. I tried using Escape button, But it is inconsistent.

Please suggest me about this

Please have a look at the alert that appears

[image]

Comment: You can accept and cancel using actions class. did not try in google?

Comment: Tried in google, When i use accept or cancel using actions it throws me an error "Alert not found"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Chrome notifications (Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343423/disable-chrome-notifications-selenium)